# Format decimal values on a BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I am displaying a double to the user, but it is printed as 1.00000000001

However, I need only two digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a class called Formatter that can do the trick.  Here's a code snippet:

```
double value = 1.24790000001;
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
String formatted = formatter.formatNumber(value, 2);
```

And, here's a link to the JavaDoc: [javax.microedition.global.Formatter](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/javax/microedition/global/Formatter.html)

Answer (score -4):

Have you looked at String.format e.g.

```
String x = String.format("%.2f", number);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: it shows error as the method format (string,double) is undefined for the string

Comment: This is on BlackBerry which is using j2me