# How to convert Float to String with out getting E in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Any way to convert Float to string with out getting E (exponent).

```
String str = String.valueOf(floatvalue);
txtbox.settext(str);
```

and i am using `NumericTextFilter.ALLOW_DECIMAL` in my textField which allow decimal but not E.

i am getting like this `1.3453E7` but i want it something like `1.34538945213` due to e i am not able to set my value in edit text.
so any way to get value with out e.

Comment: see [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4033261/119114)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what number you're trying to format.  In the US (my locale), the number `1.3453E7` is not equal to the number `1.34538945213`.  I thought that even in locales that used the *period*, or *full stop* (`.`) to group large numbers, you wouldn't have `1.34538945213`.  So, I'm guessing what you want here.

If you just want to show `float` numbers without the `E`, then you can use the [Formatter class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/global/Formatter.html).  It does not, however, have all the same methods on BlackBerry that you might expect on other platforms.

You can try this:

```java
     float floatValue = 1.3453E7f;
     Formatter f = new Formatter();
     String str = f.formatNumber(floatValue, 1);
     text.setText(str);
```

Which will show

> 13453000.0

The `1` method parameter above indicates the number of decimal places to show, and can be anything from 1 to 15.  It can't be zero, but if you wanted to display a number without any decimal places, I would assume you would be using an `int` or a `long` for that.

If I have misunderstood your problem, please post a little more description as to what you need.

I'll also mention [this utility class that apparently can be used to do more numeric formatting on BlackBerry](http://code.google.com/p/bbnumberformat/source/browse/trunk/src/javame/text/DecimalFormat.java?r=2), although I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
Double floatValue = 1.34538945213;
Formatter f = new Formatter();
String result = f.format("%.11f", floatValue);
```

Due to the floating point presentation in java, the float value 1.34538945213 has not the same representation as the double value 1.34538945213. So, if you want to get 1.34538945213 as output, you should use a double value and format it as shown in the example.

Comment: only android support this.

Comment: but how will i set it to my textbox..it taks only string.

Comment: sorry, there is an error in my code... i try to find a solution again :)